# node.js returns undefined issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

Any ideas why I am getting `undefined` when I try to output `helpers.limitsOfToday.todayStart`? If I try to output `helpers.limitsOfToday` I can see the function.

This is my code:

*helpers.js file*

```
const limitsOfToday = () => {
    var todayStart = new Date();
    todayStart.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    var todayEnd = new Date();
    todayEnd.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

    return {
        todayStart: todayStart,
        todayEnd: todayEnd,
    }
};

module.exports = { limitsOfToday };
```

*other file*

```
const helpers = require('./helpers.js');
helpers.limitsOfToday.todayStart // this is undefined
```

Comment: Write `module.exports = limitsOfToday;` and in other file `helpers().todayStart`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `limitsOfToday` is a function and you are returning `todayStart` as a key of the returning object.

Execute `limitsOfToday` and everything should work like expected:

```
const helpers = require('./helpers.js');
helpers.limitsOfToday().todayStart; // your start date
```

Answer (score 1):

In *helpers.js* file write

```
module.exports = limitsOfToday;
```

and in other file

```
helpers().todayStart
```

Another solution is to write in helpers.js file

```
module.exports = {limitsOfToday: limitsOfToday};
```

and in other file

```
helpers.limitsOfToday().todayStart
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort. Would it be right (your second line) to be `helpers.limitsOfToday().todayStart`?

Comment: No, if you rewrite module.exports as function, your helpers variable will be just function and not object.

Answer (score 1):

You are exporting object with `limitsOfToday` method which is just a function so when you write `helpers.limitsOfToday.todayStart` you are trying to access property `todayStart` of object's method which doesn't work. What you need to do is call

```
helpers.limitsOfToday().todayStart
```

so that `limitsOfToday` method returns object with `todayStart` property that you can access.

Answer (score 0):

Update your last line to be like this
`module.exports = { limitsOfToday: limitsOfToday() };`